# iterating files in unix directory talend

Tags: talend

I have a requirement of iterating files in unix directory and read the content of the files(csv) and update some database tables.

The job will be deployed in unix server,but my IDE is installed in window.
Can anyone please help me with the process

1. How will i iterate the unix files ,which component should i use ,as i know the jars will be deployed in unix server,so no need to create a unix server connection.
2. If i know the component,then it will be easy for me to update the database table
3. How can i test this in windows ?

Thanks

Comment: SO is not to do the work for you, but help when you get stuck after trying something.

Comment: @AndyWiesendanger: I am sorry if i put my words wrong ,but if you read my question carefully you ll get to know where i am stuck ,it clearly mention that i need to know the component name which is bothering me ,and that is the first step of my job design :)

Answer (score 1):

tFileList - please see the documentation and examples on the link below

https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide60EN/tFileList

You can use UNIX style file paths and separators just fine with TOS on Windows and UNIX

To read CSV files, you can use tFileInputDelimited. 
Then you'll need an appropriate database connection component and database output component